# Get all values for the XML file in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```
<MEMBER>
                <LABEL>[None]</LABEL>
                <AT Name="DefCurrency">[None]</AT>
                <AT Name="AllowAdjs">N</AT>
                <AT Name="IsICP">N</AT>
                <AT Name="AllowAdjFromChildren">N</AT>
                <AT Name="SecurityClass">NONE</AT>
                <AT Name="UserDefined1"> </AT>
                <AT Name="UserDefined2"> </AT>
                <AT Name="UserDefined3"> </AT>
                <AT Name="HoldingCompany"></AT>
                <AT Name="SecurityAsPartner"></AT>
                <DEFAULTPARENT>#root</DEFAULTPARENT>
                <DESCRIPTION Language="English">None</DESCRIPTION>
</MEMBER>
```

I have tried the `@Name` and I get all the values such as DefCurrency, IsICP etc but I don't get the values.

See my code below.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT      
            LABEL,
        
            val

FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/MEMBER/AT')
WITH 
(
LABEL [varchar](50) '@Name',

val [varchar](50) '../AT'


)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no need to use those ancient procedures. SQL Server has supported the `xml` data type and XQuery since 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All supported versions of Microsoft SQL Server have the [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) and [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) methods available for querying the XML data type, e.g.:

```sql
declare @xml xml = '<MEMBER>
                <LABEL>[None]</LABEL>
                <AT Name="DefCurrency">[None]</AT>
                <AT Name="AllowAdjs">N</AT>
                <AT Name="IsICP">N</AT>
                <AT Name="AllowAdjFromChildren">N</AT>
                <AT Name="SecurityClass">NONE</AT>
                <AT Name="UserDefined1"> </AT>
                <AT Name="UserDefined2"> </AT>
                <AT Name="UserDefined3"> </AT>
                <AT Name="HoldingCompany"></AT>
                <AT Name="SecurityAsPartner"></AT>
                <DEFAULTPARENT>#root</DEFAULTPARENT>
                <DESCRIPTION Language="English">None</DESCRIPTION>
</MEMBER>';

select
  at.value(N'@Name', N'nvarchar(128)') as LABEL,
  at.value(N'(text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as val
from @xml.nodes(N'/MEMBER/AT') member(at);
```

Which yields the output:

| LABEL | val |
| --- | --- |
| DefCurrency | [None] |
| AllowAdjs | N |
| IsICP | N |
| AllowAdjFromChildren | N |
| SecurityClass | NONE |
| UserDefined1 |  |
| UserDefined2 |  |
| UserDefined3 |  |
| HoldingCompany |  |
| SecurityAsPartner |  |

As mentioned by @Charlieface you can also query your table directly and `cross apply` to use the `nodes()` method:

```sql
select
  at.value(N'@Name', N'nvarchar(128)') as LABEL,
  at.value(N'(text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as val
from XMLwithOpenXML
cross apply XMLData.nodes(N'/MEMBER/AT') member(at);
```

It is possible to stack multiple layers of `cross apply ... .nodes()`, so to include the content of the `LABEL` element you can modify the code like the following:

```sql
select
  label.value(N'(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as LabelValue,
  at.value(N'@Name', N'nvarchar(128)') as LABEL,
  at.value(N'(text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as val
from XMLwithOpenXML
cross apply XMLData.nodes(N'/MEMBER') nodes1(member)
cross apply member.nodes(N'LABEL') nodes2(label)
cross apply member.nodes(N'AT') nodes3(at);
```

Which yields the output:

| LabelValue | LABEL | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [None] | DefCurrency | [None] |
| [None] | AllowAdjs | N |
| [None] | IsICP | N |
| [None] | AllowAdjFromChildren | N |
| [None] | SecurityClass | NONE |
| [None] | UserDefined1 |  |
| [None] | UserDefined2 |  |
| [None] | UserDefined3 |  |
| [None] | HoldingCompany |  |
| [None] | SecurityAsPartner |  |

In all likelihood, though, you're not wanting to repeat the `LABEL` element's value across multiple rows so you can instead use XQuery to filter on the `Name` attributes and effectively pivot the data with the following:

```sql
select
  label.value(N'(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as LabelValue,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="DefCurrency"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as DefCurrency,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="AllowAdjs"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as AllowAdjs,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="IsICP"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as IsICP,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="AllowAdjFromChildren"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as AllowAdjFromChildren,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="SecurityClass"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as SecurityClass,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="UserDefined1"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as UserDefined1,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="UserDefined2"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as UserDefined2,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="UserDefined3"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as UserDefined3,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="HoldingCompany"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as HoldingCompany,
  member.value(N'(AT[@Name="SecurityAsPartner"]/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(128)') as SecurityAsPartner
from XMLwithOpenXML
cross apply XMLData.nodes(N'/MEMBER') nodes1(member)
cross apply member.nodes(N'LABEL') nodes2(label);
```

| LabelValue | DefCurrency | AllowAdjs | IsICP | AllowAdjFromChildren | SecurityClass | UserDefined1 | UserDefined2 | UserDefined3 | HoldingCompany | SecurityAsPartner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [None] | [None] | N | N | N | NONE |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: OP: to use your table you would do `...FROM XMLwithOpenXML x CROSS APPLY x.XMLData .nodes(...`

Comment: Ok this works. How would i then add <LABEL>[None]</LABEL> to the output ?